# Can't go to the next page using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to tell Scrapy to move to the next page and scrape the content but it stops at the first page.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class CasaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'house'
    start_urls = ['https://www.casa.it/affitto/residenziale/napoli/montecalvario-avvocata-san-giuseppe-porto-pendino-mercato?sortType=date_desc']
       

rules = [
    (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/immobili/.*'), deny=(r'/immagine-.*')), 
        callback='parse', follow = False)),
]

def parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'title': response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()').get(),
        'price': response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/text()').get()
    }

    next_page = response.css('a.paginator__page.tp-a--c.b-r--100.is-block.c-bg--w.tp-w--m.paginator__nav.next::attr(href)').get()
    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
    if next_page is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

Do you have any idea on what I might be doing wrong? When I test the code for `next_page` in the shell I get the correct result.

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Yes I'm getting the first page results correctly. Would you be so kind to point out the mistakes you're seeing? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another rule for the pages:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class CasaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'house'
    start_urls = ['https://www.casa.it/affitto/residenziale/napoli/montecalvario-avvocata-san-giuseppe-porto-pendino-mercato?sortType=date_desc']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/affitto/residenziale/napoli/montecalvario-avvocata-san-giuseppe-porto-pendino-mercato/*')), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/immobili/.*'), deny=(r'/immagine-.*')), callback='parse', follow=False),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()').get(),
            'price': response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/text()').get()
        }
```